# etcd v2: etcd-server is healthy but etcd-events is not joining ("cluster ID mismatch" and "unmatched member while checking PeerURLs" errors)

Tags: etcd, kops, etcdctl

I have a legacy Kubernetes cluster running etcd v2 with 3 masters (etcd-a, etcd-b, etcd-c). We attempted an upgrade to etcd v3 but this broken the first master (etcd-a) and it was no longer able to join the cluster. After some time I was able to restore it:

1. removed etcd-a from etcd cluster with `etcdctl member rm`
2. added a new etcd-a1 with a clean state and added to the cluster `etcdctl member add`
3. started kubelet with `ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE` set to `existing`, then started protokube. At this point the master is able to join the cluster.

At the beginning I thought the cluster was healthy:

```
/ # etcdctl member list
a4***b2: name=etcd-c peerURLs=http://etcd-c.internal.mydomain.com:2380 clientURLs=http://etcd-c.internal.mydomain.com:4001
cf***97: name=etcd-a1 peerURLs=http://etcd-a1.internal.mydomain.com:2380 clientURLs=http://etcd-a1.internal.mydomain.com:4001
d3***59: name=etcd-b peerURLs=http://etcd-b.internal.mydomain.com:2380 clientURLs=http://etcd-b.internal.mydomain.com:4001

/ # etcdctl cluster-health
member a4***b2 is healthy: got healthy result from http://etcd-c.internal.mydomain.com:4001
member cf***97 is healthy: got healthy result from http://etcd-a1.internal.mydomain.com:4001
member d3***59 is healthy: got healthy result from http://etcd-b.internal.mydomain.com:4001
cluster is healthy
```

Yet the status of etcd-events is not great. etcd-events for a1 is not running

```
etcd-server-events-ip-a1       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   430
etcd-server-events-ip-b        1/1     Running            3
etcd-server-events-ip-c        1/1     Running            0
```

Logs from etcd-events-a1:

```
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://etcd-events-a1.internal.mydomain.com:4002
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/etcd/data-events
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=http://etcd-events-a1.internal.mydomain.com:2381
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER=etcd-events-a1=http://etcd-events-a1.internal.mydomain.com:2381,etcd-events-b=http://etcd-events-b.internal.mydomain.com:2381,etcd-events-c=http://etcd-events-c.internal.mydomain.com:2381
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE=existing
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN=etcd-cluster-token-etcd-events
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:4002
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:2381
flags: recognized and used environment variable ETCD_NAME=etcd-events-a1
etcdmain: etcd Version: 2.2.1
etcdmain: Git SHA: 75f8282
etcdmain: Go Version: go1.5.1
etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 2, total number of available CPUs is 2
etcdmain: the server is already initialized as member before, starting as etcd member...
etcdmain: listening for peers on http://0.0.0.0:2381
etcdmain: listening for client requests on http://0.0.0.0:4002
netutil: resolving etcd-events-b.internal.mydomain.com:2381 to 10.15.***:2381
netutil: resolving etcd-events-a1.internal.mydomain.com:2381 to 10.15.***:2381
etcdmain: stopping listening for client requests on http://0.0.0.0:4002
etcdmain: stopping listening for peers on http://0.0.0.0:2381
etcdmain: error validating peerURLs {ClusterID:5a***b3 Members:[&{ID:a7***32 RaftAttributes:{PeerURLs:[http://etcd-events-b.internal.mydomain.com:2381]} Attributes:{Name:etcd-events-b ClientURLs:[http://etcd-events-b.internal.mydomain.com:4002]}} &{ID:cc***b3 RaftAttributes:{PeerURLs:[https://etcd-events-a.internal.mydomain.com:2381]} Attributes:{Name:etcd-events-a ClientURLs:[https://etcd-events-a.internal.mydomain.com:4002]}} &{ID:7f***2ca RaftAttributes:{PeerURLs:[http://etcd-events-c.internal.mydomain.com:2381]} Attributes:{Name:etcd-events-c ClientURLs:[http://etcd-events-c.internal.mydomain.com:4002]}}] RemovedMemberIDs:[]}: unmatched member while checking PeerURLs

# restart
...

etcdserver: restarting member eb***3a in cluster 96***07 at commit index 3
raft: eb***a3a became follower at term 12407
raft: newRaft eb***3a [peers: [], term: 12407, commit: 3, applied: 0, lastindex: 3, lastterm: 1]
etcdserver: starting server... [version: 2.2.1, cluster version: to_be_decided]
etcdserver: added local member eb***3a [http://etcd-events-a1.internal.mydomain.com:2381] to cluster 96***07
etcdserver: added member 7f***ca [http://etcd-events-c.internal.mydomain.com:2381] to cluster 96***07
rafthttp: request sent was ignored (cluster ID mismatch: remote[7f***ca]=5a***b3, local=96***07)
rafthttp: request sent was ignored (cluster ID mismatch: remote[7f***ca]=5a***3, local=96***07)
rafthttp: failed to dial 7f***ca on stream Message (cluster ID mismatch)
rafthttp: failed to dial 7f***ca on stream MsgApp v2 (cluster ID mismatch)
etcdserver: added member a7***32 [http://etcd-events-b.internal.mydomain.com:2381] to cluster 96***07
rafthttp: request sent was ignored (cluster ID mismatch: remote[a7***32]=5a***b3, local=96***07)
rafthttp: failed to dial a7***32 on stream MsgApp v2 (cluster ID mismatch)

...

rafthttp: request sent was ignored (cluster ID mismatch: remote[a7***32]=5a***b3, local=96***07)
osutil: received terminated signal, shutting down...
etcdserver: aborting publish because server is stopped
```

Logs from etcd-events-b:

```
rafthttp: streaming request ignored (cluster ID mismatch got 96***07 want 5a***b3)
rafthttp: the connection to peer cc***b3 is unhealthy
```

Logs from etcd-events-c:

```
etcdserver: failed to reach the peerURL(https://etcd-events-a.internal.mydomain.com:2381) of member cc***b3 (Get https://etcd-events-a.internal.mydomain.com:2381/version: dial tcp 10.15.131.7:2381: i/o timeout)
etcdserver: cannot get the version of member cc***b3 (Get https://etcd-events-a.internal.mydomain.com:2381/version: dial tcp 10.15.131.7:2381: i/o timeout)
```

From the log I saw two problems:

- etcd-events on 1a seems to ignore the existing cluster (then IDs doesn't match).
- the other nodes (b and c) still somehow remembers the removed old node a.

I'm short of ideas on how to fix this. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried to upgrade etcd2 and did not restart all the masters at the same time, you will fail the upgrade.

Make sure you read through https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/etcd3-migration/
I also *strongly* recommend using the latest possible version of kOps as there are quite a few migration bugs fixed along the way.

There may be multiple reasons why the cluster ID changed, but if I remember correctly, replacing members like that was never really supported and with etcd2 your options are limited. Trying to get to etcd-manager and etcdv3 may be the best way to get your cluster in a working state again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarifications. Do you think I should be able to upgrade to etcd3 in the current status of my cluster?

Comment: The failing master probably started running etcd-manager and _may_ have started to do backups. Have a look at your s3 bucket and see if you can find any there. Should be in `<bucket>/<cluster>/backups/etcd/main`. If it did, then at least you have backups. The problem is that your revert may inadvertently started a new cluster on your broken master. And this means it may be hard to recover without one.

Comment: Btw, recommend the kops-users slack channel on the kubernetes workspace for help with things like this.